# Existence of a continuous one to one map from the set $A= \{z \in \Bbb C : z \neq 0 \}$ to the set $B = \{z \in \Bbb C : |z|>1 \}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

Does there exist a continuous one to one map from the set $A= \{z \in \Bbb C : z \neq 0 \}$ to the set $B = \{z \in \Bbb C : |z|>1 \}$?

I have tried to find this map though I have failed to do this. Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(z)=e^{\lvert z\rvert}\frac{z}{\lvert z\rvert}.$$

Comment: This map is clearly continuous and since $z \neq 0$ so we have $|z|>0 \implies |f(z)|=|e^{|z|}|>1$ i.e. $f$ maps $A$ into $B$. But why is it one to one?

Comment: @charMD No, on $(0,\infty)$ it's $e^x$, which is strictly increasing.

Comment: @D_C Try to write its inverse.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path do you mean that here $f$ is a bijection.

Comment: @D_C Even better, it's a homeomorphism.

Comment: The inverse is $w \mapsto {\frac {w} {|w|}} \ln |w|$. Which is again continuous. Isn't it so?

Comment: So $A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic. oh! great. Thanks @SaucyO'Path for your prompt help.

Answer (score 1):

$f(z)=z+\frac{z}{|z|}.$

The geometric meaning is: for a vector $z\neq 0$, we put it away from the origin $1$ unit in the direction of $z$, the inverse is pull it back $1$ unit.